# Excel FIND formula that returns 0 not Excel's error #Value + exclamation mark

Tags: excel-formula

I have cell values that are prefix with `#)` (where `#` is an alpha-numerical character). I want to get rid of this prefix and leave just the remainder of the cell's value. I have this formula:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(B15,(LEN(B15)-FIND(")",B15,1))))
```

The problem is that not all cells have this prefix and the `FIND` function results in an error when there is no prefix; instead it leaves behind `#Value!`.

Comment: Just wrap `find()` in `iferror(find(), 0)` If it returns a `#VALUE` then you'll get a `0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could test the cell for the ")" character in position 2.

For example:=IF(MID(B15,2,1)<>")",B15,RIGHT(B15,LEN(B15)-2)).

Note that if your data is not well formatted, ie the ) character is not always at position 2, use TRIM(B15) to deal with leading spaces.